# Incrementing hexa strings in Python

Tags: python

I'm trying in python to increment hexa decimal values that are represented in strings
like `'84B8042100FE'`, how can i increment this value with 1 to have `'84B8042100FF'` ?

thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
>>> s = '84B8042100FE'
>>> num = int(s, 16) + 1
>>> hex(num)[2:].upper()
'84B8042100FF'
```

And the much better method I always forget about - Thanks @Martijn Pieters

```
>>> '{:X}'.format(num)
'84B8042100FF'
```

Comment: Should also put a `.rstrip("L")` at the end in case the number is too large.

Answer (score 2):

```
In [15]: '{:X}'.format(int('84B8042100FE', 16)+1)
Out[15]: '84B8042100FF'
```

Comment: The solution of jon is good working,when i try your solution i got the error ValueError: zero length field name in format

Comment: @Ismail This is for Python 2.7 for 2.6 you need `{0:X}`